# send and receive voice message via bluetooth android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, voice, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to send and receive voice mail via bluetooth.
But fail to do that, i searched alot but didnt found a gud tutorial for that.

can any body help me?

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong
Thanks alot

Here is my `Updated Class` **BluetoothChat**:

```
public class BluetoothChat extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    boolean isRoute = true;

    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

    // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
    // Layout Views
    private ListView mConversationView;
    private EditText mOutEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    ToggleButton mspeakButton, mplayButton;

    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Array adapter for the conversation thread
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    // String buffer for outgoing messages
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    // Member object for the chat services
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
    static AudioManager mAudioManager;
    MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private MediaRecorder myRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
    File file;
    private String outputFile = null;
    boolean toggle = true;
    String items = "";
    String address = "";
    String sdcard_path = "";
    private TextView text1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        // Set up the window layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //outputFile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("output");

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // store it to sd card
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myRecording.mp3";

        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;

        }
        else {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        }
        else {
            if (mChatService == null)
                setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
        mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
        mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
        mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
                //SetRouteSco(BluetoothChat.this, isRoute);
            }
        });

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        // Initialize the speak button with a listener that for click events
        mspeakButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button_speak);

        mspeakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (toggle) {
                    toggle = false;
                    sendvoice(v);
                }
                else {
                    toggle = true;
                    record(v);
                }

            }
        });

        // Initialize the play button with a listener that for click events

        mplayButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);

        mplayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (toggle) {
                    toggle = false;
                    stopPlay(v);
                }
                else {
                    toggle = true;
                    play(v);
                }

            }
        });

        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }

    public void sendvoice(View view) {
        try {
            myRecorder.stop();
            myRecorder.release();
            myRecorder = null;

            text1.setText("Recording Point: Stop recording");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                Log.d("btAdapter", "btAdapter" + mBluetoothAdapter);
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("/myRecording.mp3");
                sharingIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
                file = new File(outputFile);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(sharingIntent);
                Log.d("/myRecording.mp3", "SharingIntent");

            }
            else {
                text1.setText("Bluetooth not activated");
            }

        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            //  it is called before start()
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // no valid audio/video data has been received
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void record(View view) {
        try {
            myRecorder.prepare();
            myRecorder.start();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // start:it is called before prepare()
            // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat() 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // prepare() fails
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        text1.setText("Recording Point: Recording");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stopPlay(View view) {
        try {
            if (myPlayer != null) {
                myPlayer.stop();
                myPlayer.release();
                myPlayer = null;

                text1.setText("Recording Point: Stop playing");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop playing the recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        try {
            myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
            myPlayer.prepare();
            myPlayer.start();

            text1.setText("Recording Point: Playing");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start play the recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
        if (mChatService != null)
            mChatService.stop();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "onReceive");
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                items += device.getName() + ",";
                address += device.getAddress() + ",";
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Sends a message.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            A string of text to send.
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }
    }

    // The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
                //SetRouteSco(BluetoothChat.this, isRoute);
            }
            if (D)
                Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
            return true;
        }
    };

    private final void setStatus(int resId) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
    }

    private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
    }

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if (D)
                    Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    try {
                        setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);

                /*String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                try {
                    re(readMessage);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);*/
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    /*  public void play(String outputFile) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {

            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
            m.setDataSource(outputFile);
            m.prepare();
            m.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    */
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            }
            else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        mChatService.connect(device, secure);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent serverIntent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.secure_connect_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.insecure_connect_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*  *//**
     * Sends a voice message.
     */
    /*
    public static void SetRouteSco(Context context, boolean isRoute) {
    Log.d("SetRouteSco", "isRoute  : " + isRoute);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(isRoute);
    if (isRoute)
        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    else
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
    }*/

}
```

**XML**:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Recording Point: -"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_speak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="send"
        android:textOn="speak" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Msg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="stop"
        android:textOn="play" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest Class**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.BluetoothChat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MAinActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".BluetoothChat"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**NOTE:** Firstly I paired my device with another and voice is recorded successfully but while sending that voice to another device, "You are not connected to the device" toast is displayed

**IMPORTANT :** By this demo my audio file is send, but it only save directly to the sd card,
I want that audio file first should send to that specific application and also save to the sd card

Anyone can help me??
How can I do this?

Thanks In Advanced

Comment: Do you want to play voice message using Bluetooth or transfer that voice message?

Comment: @Palak  : I want both

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish paring between two device for transfer voice message

1) Record voice message using your application

2) send it using share via Bluetooth.

Comment: I had done with pairing of two devices but I'm unable to send and receive voice message..

Comment: On which android operating system your are testing?

Comment: Successfully connect with two device
got the Toast in 2nd connect device "Playing audio".
You need to send file instead of text.
Could you able to write a code for send file?

Comment: i had wrote that, check mainActivity class

Comment: on the click of stop button i passed the intent in MainActivity

Comment: In manifest give intentfilter to the MainActivity class and then check it

Comment: When i pass the intent on the click of stop it send the path ("/myrecording.3gp") instead to send the voice message

Comment: also MianActivity is not called from anywhere

Comment: I had uploaded manifest class here
Replace this class with that one

Comment: HI palak
i have uplaoded my updated class
can you check it?
n let me knw where i'm wrong

Comment: Your class not match with Xml layout and also describe your project flow